# Mining wallets - how to?

Tags: miner-configuration

all I want to know is what do I do when using a mining software and it asks me for a wallet address... I've tried to use bitcoin address etc but it doesn't work! says invalid wallet! where to get a valid wallet to mine!.

a simple answer will suffice thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but a "mining wallet" doesn't exist. There's only cloud mining that is questionable. The rest don't won't hurt you so feel free to explore. Just avoid 1) malware 2) Paying (even if they say you have $3k, pay to withdraw)

Comment: ok maybe I wasnt clear on what i am looking for.... when you config a miner they ask you for a wallet address. right? but if you insert your receiving address for bitcoin or whatever crypto you are mining it wont accept that wallet address.... why?

Comment: It should. I doubt it that what you have a is a miner. You can see how a decent miner looks like here https://www.prnewswire.co.uk/news-releases/bitmain-announces-specs-for-next-gen-antminer-s19-and-s19-pro-coming-soon-861798654.html which dont ask you for your address but your pool ip and login credentials instead

Comment: its a miner its the T-rex miner got it properly from the github website. you say its a pool address? so I need to have a hardware miner to do it by myself cant do it with software? so i need to use nicehash?